# How to disable Style Cop visual studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

How to disable the Style Cop visual studio extension? It's not listed in Tools / Extensions or in Tools / Add-in manager

Comment: Did you restart VS after you were done? That should fix it

Comment: Yes, but it didn't fix it. There was an error message about extensions.  Just restarted my whole computer, but Style Cop remains, bleeding. This is Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Fixed it by running `devenv.exe /setup` but BEWARE I don't know what this does it may have had unintended side effects

Comment: /setup forces Visual Studio to merge the resource metadata that describes menus, toolbars, and command groups, from all available VSPackages. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad.aspx)

All of my extensions are running properly so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't, StyleCop deliberately hides itself from the uninstall menu in Visual Studio.

You can uninstall it in Add/Remove programs. You might get an error the next time you open Visual Studio but it will be gone after that.

Answer (score 46):

I had the same issue: I uninstalled it using *Add/Remove programs* and got the expected error, when I opened Visual Studio next time. Still after hiding this error message, the StyleCop entries remained in my context menus.

After some research, I found a solution to remove all remains by running `devenv.exe /setup` on the command prompt. You must run the console elevated and you might have to switch to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` folder (or similar; depending on your system) in order to run the command.

Remember to remove the assotiated Code Cleanup profile if you are using ReSharper.

Source: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/257772

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I was doomed to having these orphaned context menu items forever.

Answer (score 7):

why it happens is : mostly because you uninstalled the style-cop while visual studio was open

how to fix it

1. remove the registry keys

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\InstalledProducts\StyleCop
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Packages{629EB7CC-69C2-43AC-9BC9-482B0F810C4E}

OR

2. reinstall & then uninstall (make sure your visual studio is closed during this process)

**if you are using resharper**

you would need to reset the `Code Cleanup Profile` to factory defualt to get rid of style-cop completely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have already uninstalled it from Visual Studio by ReSharper Extension Manager and it there was under the right click menu still when I click any projects on Solution Explorer.

This way will solve the problem:

Steps:

- Remove the StyleCop by Add/Remove Programs on control panel
- If you have already uninstalled the StyleCop, install once again by ReSharper extension manager.(There will be many error at the first opening Visual Studio after the styleCop uninstall process. don't worry about it, press enter all)
- Then Remove it by Resharper extension manager again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the VS15 StyleCop plug-in installed and later added the ReSharper extension on top.

I removed the extension from ReSharper, then uninstalled StyleCop via Control Panel Add/Remove Programs and then let CCleaner run with registry clean-up.

The StyleCop entries have disappeared from the menus and the billions of squiggly lines have as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install "StyleCop" extension from Visual Studio Marketplace. Which also can be found from the link :
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop

Now right click your project and click on "StyleCop Settings", there you you can disable or customize the rules.